# multiple array in Table material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have multiple array inside state, how do I iterate it and show inside table component?

Here's my state

```js
this.state= {
  title: [],
  animal: [],
}
```

I want to show something like

```js
title  | icon           | animal |
1      | <deleteIcon/>  | cat    |
2      | <deleteIcon/>  | dog    |
3      | <deleeteIcon/> | bird   |
```

I tried to mapping each array but when it renders all the data show in a row instead column, I dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: Would you share how the underlying data source looks like? A schema/shape of `title` and `animal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably making a mistake with `<td></td>` and `<tr></tr>` placement. A simple program that does what you expect is shown here.

```
function App() {
  let tile =[1, 2, 3]
  let animal =['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <tr><td>title</td><td>icon</td><td>animal</td></tr>
    {tile.map((elem, i) => {
      return (<tr>
      <td>{i}</td><td>deleteIcon</td><td>{animal[i]}</td>
      </tr>)
      })
    } 
    </div>
  );
}
```